# Swift: How can I save and load a dictionary with values of a structure in Userdefaults

Tags: swift, dictionary, structure, nsuserdefaults

I've read some posts on the subject on StackOverflow. As far as I understood it, I can't save every object in Swift immediately in the userdefaults.
In the first step I tried to convert my dictionary to an NSData object, but already at this point, I fail.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

I want to manage app preferences in the mentioned dictionary. The dictionary with the value of a struct would be the best solution for me.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


struct Properties: Codable {
    var v1: String
    var v2: Int
    var v3: Bool
}


let userdefaults = UserDefaults.standard

var dictStruct: Dictionary<String, Properties> = [:]

dictStruct["a"] = Properties(v1: "AAA", v2: 0, v3: false)
dictStruct["b"] = Properties(v1: "BBB", v2: 1, v3: true)


let dataEncoded: Data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictStruct, requiringSecureCoding: false)

userdefaults.set(dataEncoded, forKey: "KeyData")

let dataDecoded = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(userdefaults.object(forKey: "KeyData") as! Data) as! Dictionary<String, Properties>

print(dataDecoded["a"]!.v1)
```

> Playground execution terminated: An error was thrown and was not caught:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4866 "Caught exception during archival: -[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000fc73c0
>   ...

Comment: Codable has nothing to do with NSCoding. So `Dictionary<String, Properties>` is is not NSCoding compliant. You can simply write the data to a plist file instead of trying to write it to UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up `Codable` and `NSCoding`. `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver` belongs to `NSCoding`. Don't use it.

The proper API for `Codable` is `PropertyListEncoder/-Decoder`

```
struct Properties: Codable {
    var v1: String
    var v2: Int
    var v3: Bool
}

let userdefaults = UserDefaults.standard

var dictStruct: Dictionary<String, Properties> = [:]

dictStruct["a"] = Properties(v1: "AAA", v2: 0, v3: false)
dictStruct["b"] = Properties(v1: "BBB", v2: 1, v3: true)

do {
    let dataEncoded = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(dictStruct)

    userdefaults.set(dataEncoded, forKey: "KeyData")

    if let data = userdefaults.data(forKey: "KeyData") {
       let dataDecoded = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([String:Properties].self, from: data)
       print(dataDecoded["a"]!.v1)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both of you saved my evening ;-)